# Saving Breeze entities manually and updating keyMappings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I want to manually save entities in Breeze.  We just don't have the option (as much as I try to fight for my opinion) to use the SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) and need to directly hit a 3rd party Web API with a specific URL for POST/PUT requests.

So I am basically looping through EntityManager.getChanges() and then handling Modified, Added, and Deleted entities.

I can handle the "Modified" without any problems.  However, on "Added", I know I need to update keyMappings when I add a new entity after successful save but cannot find any documentation on how to do that manually in JavaScript.

I also wanted to see if there any examples in returning any errors.  Basically I want to hook into this call:

```
 $http(params).then(
                        function (response) { // success 
                            console.log(response);
                          // update key mappings if its an "Added" somehow
                          //  entityAspect.acceptChanges();
                            dfd.resolve("something eventually");
                        },
                        function () { // error 
                            // added error object here and reject changes on this entity? or just show error message?
                            dfd.reject("error");
                        });
                return dfd.promise;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone's wondering, I just check the entityAspect.entityState.isAdded() method.  Get the new identity returned from my 3rd party and just update the id accordingly.  Our system is a little bit nicer in that we have a set key for all of the entities.

Code wise it looks something like this (dfd is a $q defer):

```
 $http(params).then(function (response) { // success 

                        // on add update the instance id with the new instance id
                        if (entityState.isAdded()) {
                            var newId = response.data.changedInstance.newId; 
                            entity.Id = newId ;
                        }

                        entityAspect.acceptChanges();  
                        dfd.resolve(response.data); 
                    },
                    function (response) { // error  
                        dfd.reject(response.data);
                    });
```